# SQL to Subtract timestamps in same column but different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, aggregate-functions

We have an SQL table where a machine logs data to.
To get a better insight in the process timing we want to subtract the timestamps so we can see the variance in timing.

Is there a way to do this? 
Below an example of our table in the database:

```
TS                          |Tag                                |Description        |Value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-06-12 14:13:12.253     |DB26_Mp370_MachineStatus           |Machine Status     |Event 4
2020-06-12 14:12:56.250     |DB26_Mp370_MachineStatus           |Machine Status     |Event 3
2020-06-12 14:12:26.250     |DB26_Mp370_MachineStatus           |Machine Status     |Event 2
2020-06-12 14:11:06.253     |DB26_Mp370_MachineStatus           |Machine Status     |Event 1
```

Result should be something like:

```
TS                          |Tag                                |Description        |Value      |TimeDiff
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-06-12 14:13:12.253     |DB26_Mp370_MachineStatus           |Machine Status     |Event 4    | 16.003
2020-06-12 14:12:56.250     |DB26_Mp370_MachineStatus           |Machine Status     |Event 3    | 30.000
2020-06-12 14:12:26.250     |DB26_Mp370_MachineStatus           |Machine Status     |Event 2    | 19.997
2020-06-12 14:11:06.253     |DB26_Mp370_MachineStatus           |Machine Status     |Event 1    |
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is `lag()`.  However, date/time functions differ among databases.  The idea is something like:

```
(ts -
 lag(ts) over (partition by tag order by ts)
)
```

However, not all databases necessarily support `-` on "timestamps", so you might need to adjust that.

Comment: Thanks! Added two columns. 1 giving datetime format, one gib=ving numeric value in milliseconds
(ts - lag(ts) over (partition by tag order by ts)) as timediff
,DATEDIFF(millisecond,0,cast((ts -lag(ts) over (partition by tag order by ts)) as datetime)) as diffms

Comment: @AndyJansen . . . Those would seem like the right constructs for SQL Server.